# What to do with questions that will have a different answer each year?

Tags: discussion

There are some questions on good tablet/smartphone apps/sites/resources for GMing and playing. They are, unfortunately, years old, and I am sure that there have been and will be new releases and updates that improve on the current crop and provide new options for GMs and players of different systems.

Should these questions be bumped or should new questions be asked or should this transient topic be handled in another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a necromancer badge just for that...  Adding more answers generally prompts the question to be seen on the front page and thus new members keep adding new answers and upvoting the old ones.  If in doubt, you can always open a new question (which will be closed as duplicate) or use the "search" feature of the site or Google.

Comment: +1.  Questions and answers are evergreen here, can always be edited (by those with rep), etc.  asking the question again will always get it closed as duplicate.  Edit, bounty, add new answers to the old one.

Comment: Adding a bounty is preferable and more effective than making a duplicate question.